# Bottoms of share and other buttons cut off

Tags: php, css, concrete5

I am building a site in Concrete5 that uses an addon for the blog, and on [the page](http://concrete.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/index.php/blog/2013/07/test-image/) type for individual posts there are share buttons for social media. For some reason the bottoms of the buttons are being cut off. I've tried using Firebug and Chrome dev tools to find the source of the problem, but have been unable to find the culprit style. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The height of your span is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your CSS and add this:

```
.stButton .stMainServices{
min-height: 30px;
}
```

Now it should work fine.