# Wordpress.org Social Media Button Bubble Counter cut off at bottom

Tags: css, share-button

I had a problem with share buttons being cut off at the bottom on my site and have fixed using this helpful post:

[Bottoms of share and other buttons cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912700/bottoms-of-share-and-other-buttons-cut-off)

Now I am trying to to do the same for the little button bubble that shows the counter next to the share button.

Originally had this problem:

[image: Share buttons cut off]

Now I have fixed the buttons but the bubble counter is still the same, but not all of them as you can see from image:

[image: Share bubble cut off]

Not sure what CSS I need to fix. I tried using inspect element from right clicking using browser but not sure what code to rework.

Many thanks for any helpful tips to get me on my way.

Andrew

Comment: post a link of your site or post some code.

Comment: Code to fix buttons:

   .stButton .stMainServices{
   min-height: 23px;
   }

   Site: http://yourhealthandvitality.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
.stButton .stButton_gradient 
{
   height: 22px;
}
```

This is what I get under Chrome on Windows[image]:

Comment: Still get same problem with button counter bubble cut off.

Comment: thats weird it looks fine to me. which browser are u using? For me it works fine on FF and Chrome.

Comment: Chrome. If you look directly under the counter number it is cut off. You can still see the number - just. The FB like one is ok for some reason but others aren't.

Comment: I added a picture for you to see what I get what I change the style to height: 22px; @Andrew

Comment: Thanks for sharing I'll need to check why CSS code is not applying this. I downloaded a plugin that lets me add custom CSS, it worked ok for the buttons but not this it seems.